# Getting a DbUpdateConcurrencyException after deleting all data from database

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

My senario is: We have a production and an integration database and I wrote a tool to migrate some of the data of the production database to the integration database. For this I use: Entity Framework 6.0, .NET-Framework 4.5.2 and the databases are MS SQL Server Standard (64-bit) 13.0.5102.

My problem: While saving the deletion of all data in the integration database, the `SaveChanges` method throw an `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` with the error message

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.

The following is the code that through the exception:

```cs
using (var prod = new DbProdContext())
{
    using (var @int = new DbIntContext())
    using (var transaction = @int.Database.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable))
    {
        try
        {
            var stack = BuildStack(@int, ...); // buikds a stack of the tables where the latest pushed tables depdend only on already pushed tables

            // Deleting everything in db
            using (var x = log4net.NDC.Push("Deleting old content"))
            {
                foreach (var table in stack.Reverse())
                {
                    var destSet = table.DestSet;
                    destSet.RemoveRange(destSet);
                }

                log.Info("Saving Changes...");
                @int.SaveChanges(); // <-- throw exception
                log.Info("Completed Saving Changes");
            }

            // code to insert the data

            transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // log
            transaction.Rollback();
        }
    }
}
```

Note: The variable `stack` is a stack of the table in the integration database where for any given table `t` all table which `t` depends on are pushed onto the stack before `t` is pushed onto the stack.

Seoncond note: I tested the code with migration the data from a local test clone of the production database into the integration database which never throw this exception.

Does any body know how to prevent this error or what caused it.

Third note: The integration database it currently note in use to there could not be a concurrent change to the database from a different process.

Should I maybe just create sql drop statements for the tables instead of using `destSet.RemoveRange(destSet)`

Answer (score 0):

> Should I maybe just create sql drop statements for the tables instead of using destSet.RemoveRange(destSet)

Yes.  You should do that.  But if you don't want to recreate the tables, it should be DELETE or TRUNCATE TABLE instead of DROP TABLE.